# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:7169/_framework/dotnet.js

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0, release-candidate

Good day

I am working on a new blazor app, .NET 8 RC 1 and while the app seems to work locally as I am debugging and making changes, this error pops up in the developer tools (browser) console:

What is it, and how do I fix this?

GET https://localhost:7169/_framework/dotnet.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:7169/_framework/dotnet.js

[image]

Comment: I realize this is not the solution, but doing this for the time being removed that error - likely since I am now using server side rendering for everything ;-)

App.Razor:


<body>
    <Routes @rendermode=@RenderMode.Server />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: i am getting same issue - been searching for a comprehensive explanation on why this is happening but so far hasnt been able to find any info on this. i want to keep using RenderMode.InteractiveAuto - but getting the same error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://{base.uri}/_framework/dotnet.js"

Comment: @YanD Have you been able to find a conclusion on this issue since? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same error and discovered that the cause in my case was related to the ASP.NET Core Server Project. Specifically, the issue was with the following line (Program.cs):

```
host.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
```

Interestingly, this line is not included in the Blazor Web App Template, which led me to believe that it might no longer be valid.

The error became apparent when I was updating from .NET 7 to .NET 8. Dan Roth, a prominent figure in the .NET community, has also mentioned similar issues when upgrading projects. You can find more details on his GitHub page: [Dan Roth's Net8BlazorWebAssembly](https://github.com/danroth27/Net8BlazorWebAssembly).

If you're facing similar problems after upgrading, I recommend following Dan Roth's upgrade advice."

Comment: Thanks Patrizio. i am seeing this issue on a freshly Blazor Web App project. i have a couple of projects in progress at a stage where it is easy enough for me to move existing Blazor components into a new project rather than attempting to upgrade existing .net-7 blazor projects.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue, I resolved it by moving my WebAssembly components to a new `BlazorWebAssembly` project.

Use this command to generate an example project with working WebAssembly render mode, and compare the differences to what you have:

```
dotnet new blazor -o BlazorApp -int Auto
```

A quick summary of the changes in the generated project:

- `AdditionalAssemblies` is `Routes.razor`
- `AddAdditionalAssemblies` being used in `Program.cs`
- A `Client` WebAssembly project

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because the client (browser) has not been able to download the Javascript module dotnet.js, this library is used to create and start the .NET WebAssembly runtime.
As you know, in a Blazor.Net 8 project it is possible through the @attribute to choose different operating modes for your page/component, examples: [RenderModeWebAssembly], [RenderModeAuto], [RenderModeServer] for example if you use the latter this library will not be necessary since Blazor the Framework uses this library blazor.web.js

Comment: Hi
Thank you for the reply, I gathered as much.
When I make use of RenderModeAuto or WebAssembly, why can it not download that dotnet.js file? is there something I can do to make sure it downloads the file successfully?

Comment: Got the same error with a basic Blazor Web App, this is a non-answer, doesn't explain what is wrong in code that causes the file to fail to load.

Comment: its obvious why this is happening - because the dotnet.js is not available - the question is WHY is it not available.

Comment: I have not recently created a fresh .NET 8.0 blazor web app, perhaps the latest .NET 8.0 release fixes this issue? If I do happen to get a chance I will test myself.