# Blazor WASM migration problem from NET 7 to NET 8 dotnet.js file is missing

Tags: blazor, webassembly, .net-8.0, mudblazor

I am trying to migrate a development Blazor WASM project from .NET 7 to .NET 8.
I have followed following article from the microsoft website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

The project builds without any error but in the chorme and edge browsers i got the following error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5193/_framework/dotnet.js
at ti (blazor.web.js:1:163957)
could someone please explain what should i do to overcome this problem.
Many Thanks

Comment: I found [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77719861) which reported the same issue, one of the answer points to `host.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();`. Could you please help check it?

Comment: Before posting my question , i have checked that ticket .I have already removed this line from my program.cs (server project) file. it was mentioned in microsoft article
Remove the following line:
diff
- app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

Comment: Please explain more or add the code, Or upload the code to GitHub, so that we can view it more accurately, and this will help us help you better.